# Authenticate ASP.Net Website request with WEB API calls

Tags: asp.net, authentication, token, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way through which I can make call from my ASP.Net website for authenticating each request , through a WEB API ?

ASP.Net Website, pages need to make calls to the WEB API for token based authentication , and based on the request get the result of the authentication process.